# How can I insert a key-value pair in an unordered map that is present in the innermost struct in rust programming language?

Tags: rust, nearprotocol, near-sdk-rs

This is my data model:

```
pub struct RaffleDetails {
    prize: Balance,
    start: Timestamp,
    end: Timestamp,
    participants: UnorderedMap<AccountId, Balance>,
}


pub struct RaffleDapp {
    raffles: UnorderedMap<AccountId, RaffleDetails>,
}
```

How can I insert a key-value pair in the 'participants' variable?

I tried `self.raffles.get(&raffle_account_id).unwrap().participants.insert(&env::predecessor_account_id(), &confidence);` but it's not persistent.

References:
[UnorderedMap](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/latest/near_sdk/collections/struct.UnorderedMap.html)
[NEAR Rust SDK](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you are updating the `RaffleDetails` instance that is in the map, not a copy/clone of it.

I'm not familiar with `UnorderedMap`, but it seems to me the `get()` method returns a **copy** of the value that is *in* the map, so you are only updating the copied value. I don't know if `UnorderedMap` allows you to mutate a value in it directly (skimming through the docs, I don't see such a method). What you can do though is re-insert the modified `RaffleDetails` into the `raffles` map (so as to *replace* the old one with the modified one).

I'm talking about something like this (I haven't tested compiling it):

```
let o = self.raffles.get(&raffle_account_id);
if let copied_rd = Some(o) {
    copied_rd.participants.insert(&env::predecessor_account_id(), &confidence);
    self.raffles.insert(&raffle_account_id, &copied_rd);
}
```

Comment: I have tried inserting by borrowing `RaffleDetails` as mutable but it's not working.

Comment: I tried `self.raffles.get(&raffle_account_id).unwrap().participants.insert(&env::predecessor_account_id(), &confidence);` but it's not persistent.

Comment: See my updated answer, pls?